# laravel many to many relationship in this case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have already checked this official example http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

but I still confused because I may have a different case.

I have a `DetailsAttribute` model which deals with `details_attribute` table.

I have a `Action` model witch deals with `action` table.

The relationship between them is many to many.

So I created a new table `details_attribute_action` with model `DetailsAttributeAction`

My `DetailsAttribute` model should have:

```
public function actions(){}
```

My `Actions` model should have:

```
public function detailsAttributes(){}
```

and my `DetailsAttributeAction` model should have functions but I don't know what they are.

My question is what is the code inside the previous functions please? and should really the `DetailsAttributeAction` have functions of not?

Comment: Function names in relations don't follow any specific rules. Did you look at Documentations? [http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many]

Comment: @revo yes I did but in the documentation there are 4 models, videos, tags, blogs and tagable but in my case I have three

Comment: What's the `DetailsAttributeAction` model?

Comment: You refer to polymorphic m-m relation. Are you sure you need this kind of relation, or maybe it's just simple many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @revo it is the model that break the `many to many` relationship

Comment: @deczo Oh really? I just need simple many to many how please?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent You tell me. I don't know what relations you need :) Describe those relationships, then I can give you my advice.

Comment: @deczo now I am sure it is a simple many to many, which I didn't know about it bty, :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Many-to-Many relation, not one that is polymorphic.
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Your code should look something like this:

```
class DetailsAttribute extends Eloquent {
    // ...

    public function actions()
    {
        // Replace action_id and details_attribute_id with the proper
        // column names in the details_attribute_action table
        return $this->belongsToMany('Action', 'details_attribute_action', 'details_attribute_id', 'action_id');
    }
}

class Action extends Eloquent {
    // ...

    public function detailsAttributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('DetailsAttribute', 'details_attribute_action', 'action_id', 'details_attribute_id');
    }
}
```

You won't have to worry about how to create the DetailsAttributeAction model in Laravel. It's simply a table to map the Many-to-Many relationships you've created.

Comment: @deczo what do you mean ? in which model are you talking about please?

Comment: In both @Nebez's examples.

Comment: @deczo Hey, you're right. Let me update that now. Thanks for pointing it out.